# DNS and DHCP addresses aren't matching up

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, dhcp

Server 2008 R2 DNS and DHCP server (same server).

For some reason over the last few months I've noticed that many of my DNS entries are incorrect.  I'll try to remote into a computer via hostname, and I end up at a different workstation than I intended.  The only way to remotely find the correct IP is to check the hostname in DHCP and then update the DNS record to correct it.

Is there something I can do to fix this issue with my DNS without having to update each DNS entry manually? Even if I did that I think that this issue would continue to present itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely having an issue with stale records that haven't been removed.  Take a look into  enabling Scavenging on your DNS zones, if you are utilizing dynamic DNS updates from your clients.  Scavenging examines the records and will remove records that have not been updated in the specified time range. Here is some info on Scavenging Settings and how to enable it:

[Enable Scavenging](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755716%28WS.10%29.aspx)

[DNS Aging and Scavenging](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757041%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: My zone is already set to scavenge every 2 days (for both settings).

Comment: Do you see entries that are more than 2 days out of date?

Comment: Oh yes definitely. I see entries that are 6 months old.

Answer (score 2):

As cheekaleak already mentioned, you need to configure and enable Aging and scavenging of stale records.

From your comments it sounds like you have *configured* the aging properties for the zone, but not *enabled* it for the server. For the actual scavenging process to take place, you need to enable scavenging on a DNS **server** that holds the zone, not on the zone itself.

The DNS Server will then perform the scavenging, according to the aging and scavenging properties you have configured on the individual zones.

**NOTE:** The actual time it takes for stale records to be removed is the sum of the configured aging intervals (+ as long as it takes before the next scavenging occurs), so if you have a no-refresh interval of 2 days, a refresh interval of 2 days, and scheduled scavenging to occur every 2 days, you might have to wait for up to as long as 6 days from the record is updated/created and possibly invalidated